# Shipping my car from Egypt to Europe

Tags: italy, automobiles, ferries, egypt

I want to drive my car from Alexandria to the automobile country of Germany. The main problem is finding a ferry that can take me to Europe. I want to know what my options are. The country that I want to ferry to is Italy.

Comment: It might be easier to drive your car to UAE or Saudi Arabia and ferry it from there.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute requirement for entering Germany/Italy is a Schengen visa, if you haven't it, you cannot enter Europe at all and the voyage is over. Given the current situation in Egypt you must be aware that you need to meet many requirements to get the visa.

Let's assume you have the visa, what next ?
The simple solution for driving in Germany is traveling via plane to Germany and rent a car.

But you want to use your own car ?
Well, then it gets difficult.

The last ferry connection from Italy to Egypt ceased to exist 2008. The last ferry connection from Haifa, Israel to Piraeus, Greece ceased to exist 2003. The way over land from Egypt over Turkey is completely blocked because of the war in Syria.
One way to enter Italy with your car is via Tunis in Tunisia to Palermo, Silicy. From Palermo it is easy to get the Italian mainland. But you need to drive through Libya to get to Tunis and it is highly unlikely that you will be able to acquire that visa.

As pnuts pointed out, the Turkish ferry system [U.N.-RORO](http://www.unroro.com) has started 2013 (so I missed it) to have a ferry service from Damietta over Haifa to İskenderun and if you drive from İskenderun to Mersin, you could ferry from Mersin to Trieste in Italy. That would be your other option.

Even if you manage to get to Tunis/Trieste, I would inform myself if you are allowed to ship your car to Italy. Not that after reaching Tunis you cannot import your car and your voyage was futile.

ADDITION: If you really pull that off, please give notice of your adventure. :)

Comment: @pnuts Hey, thank you. I did not know that the Turkish ferries etablished a new route.

Comment: So the ferry from Damietta to Iskerendun is up and running then.
any idea of who to contact or where to look for prices, bookings etc.
Thx

Comment: It appears to be possible to get a [14-day Libya transit visa](https://www.temehu.com/transitvisa.htm) to follow the coast road from Egypt to Tunisia. There also appear to be several companies providing ferry service from Tunis to Genoa, Italy, so this is quite within the realm of possibility.

Comment: I see problems with importing the car. Last time I checked importing vehicles was a very costly and complicated procedure.